# How to resolve this Exception : Data source rejected establishment of connection, message from server: "Too many connections"

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3 +Mysql 5.1 and after 98 insertion i am getting this Exception :

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

My hibernate.cfg.xml file is :

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/xml
      root
      root
      10
      false
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      update
      true

Answer (score 4):

Do you close your connections in a finally block?

something like this?

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx;
try {
   tx = sess.beginTransaction();
   //do some work
   ...
   tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
   throw e;
}
finally {
   sess.close();
}
```

If you don't you will be running out of connections.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess your application is leaking connections (opens them without properly closing them).